# How to find straight lines angles of image based on colors in OpenCV

Tags: python, c++, opencv, edge-detection

I'm trying to find angle of edge which should be detected suing predefined colors using OpenCV with C++. Python answers are also welcom.

[image: my input image] This is my input image.

[image] Annotated white line, which I should get the angel

This magenta & cyan coolers are fixed. I just only need to detect that edge between magenta & cyan and then calculate the angle of that edge (calculate the gradient of the edge line) between that predefined 2 colors. It should **not** detect all other edges. Only the edge line between magenta & cyan. But There may be slight variations of 'hue' values of the colors.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "most efficient"?

Comment: @DanMašek I thought that so many options are available. I have edit the title now. If you know any method please let me know. No need to consider efficiency.

Comment: Threshold on Magenta and get the hough lines. Then threshold on Cyan and get the Hough lines. Find which lines overlap.

Comment: Is this a true image to be processed or just a demo diagram ? Show real cases.

Comment: @YvesDaoust this image is from robot simulation platform. Upto now I just want to do it in that simulation platform. So my input image will always similar to this.

Comment: @Chamod: no, real life images are never like you think. Never.

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks for your idea. Could you give me some idea to find the overlap also ?

Comment: A brute force concept might be to draw one line in say blue and the other in red on a white or black background. Then count the number of magenta pixels. To account for some tolerance in separation, just draw thicker lines.